# batch file launched from ssh doesn't display on host

Tags: ssh, display, host

I'm trying to launch a graphic program on a host. The program is launched from a batch file which resides on the host.
My host is Windows 10, my client is Windows Server 2008.

I tried using ssh through PuTTy and and through CygWin, getting the same results.

After launching the program from the client, it is running properly on the host - I can see the CPU usage go up and the output is written to file. However, nothing is displayed on the host's screen.
I have one user on the host, Administrator, and that is the one that I logged into through ssh.

When I launch the batch file directly from the host, everything works fine - I do see the program display properly.

Any idea why this is happening?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From everything I've seen, this is indeed not possible on Windows 10, at least not without some serious hacking. Instead, we're using the Python package xmlrpc, which is great for this sort of thing.